# A binomial expansion problem I am having problem with.

Tags: contest-math, binomial-coefficients, binomial-distribution

When $ (1+cx)^n$ is expanded a series in ascending powers of $x$, the first three terms are given by $1+20x+150x^2$. Calculate the value of the constants $c$ and $n$.

If possible please include working so I could perhaps understand how you got to the answer.

Comment: Have you tried this, yourself? You said that you have problems with it, so at what point did you encounter a difficulty?

Comment: To be honest, I spent a considerable amount of time just staring at the problem looking for ideas, to no avail. I deduced that $(cx)^n-1 = 20$ and so forth.

Comment: It is $cx$ to the power of $n-1$, I'm not sure why it is displaying it like that.

Comment: Do you know any methods of expanding an arbitrary (analytical) function as an infinite series? I mean, expanding as a polynomial.

Comment: Sorry I am not too sure what you are talking about, I am only in grade 9/ year 10.

Comment: do you know how to expand $(1+y)^n$ ?

Comment: No, I've been learning how to expand using the Pascal's triangle but I am not sure how to do it with a variable instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [Binomial formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement)

Applying it you get:

$$(1+cx)^n = {n \choose 0} \cdot 1^n \cdot (cx)^{0} + {n \choose 1} \cdot 1^{n-1} \cdot 
(cx)^{1} + {n \choose 2} \cdot 1^{n-2} \cdot (cx)^{2} +\ ... $$

$$(1+cx)^n = {n \choose 0} + {n \choose 1} \cdot (cx)^{1} + {n \choose 2} \cdot (cx)^{2} +\ ... $$

$$(1+cx)^n = {n \choose 0} + {n \choose 1} \cdot cx + {n \choose 2} \cdot c^2x^{2} +\ ... $$

Now you can construct equations for $c,n$ because you are given the coefficients before $x$ and $x^2$.

$${n \choose 1} \cdot c = 20 $$
$${n \choose 2} \cdot c^2 = 150 $$

Let us solve this system of two equations.

$$nc= 20$$
$$\frac{n(n-1)}{2}c^2 = 150$$

We get

$$nc = 20$$
$$(n-1)c = 15$$

This means

$$nc = 20$$
$$nc-c = 15$$

This gives us the answer which is $c=5, n=4$

Comment: How did you simplify $$\frac{n(n-1)}{2}c^2 = 150$$ into $$(n-1)c = 15$$

Comment: I used the fact that $\frac{nc}{2}=10$

Comment: Another question sorry, how can you simplify $\binom{n}{2} $ into $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}  $? As per the identity $\binom{a}{b}=\frac{a!}{b!(a-b)!}$, wouldn't that make the simplification rather uncertain since it would become $\frac{n!}{2(n-k)!}$

Comment: @axpandey You just plug in the n and the 2 into your formula and cancel the common terms from numerator and denominator. And you end up with $\frac{n\cdot(n-1)}{1 \cdot 2}$

Answer (score 0):

$$(1+cx)^n=1+ncx+\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)(cx)^2+...$$
So we have $nc=20~~~(1)$ and $\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)c^2 =150~~~(2)$
$$\implies n(n-1)c^2=300 \implies 20 (n-1)c=300 \implies (n-1)C=15 \implies 20-c=15 $$
$$\implies c=5, n=4$$

Comment: How did you simplify $$n(n-1)c^2=300$$ into $$20(n-1)c=300$$

Comment: $n(n-1)c^2=300 \implies nc c(n-1)=300 \implies c(n-1)=15 \implies nc-c =15 \implies 20-c=15 \implies c=5$

Comment: Thank you for elaborating!